# How do you get lpr on os X to print with margins and a smaller font?

Tags: macos, unix

Printing a text file with `lpr` produces output with a large Monaco font and very thin margins. Is there a way to change the font and the margins when you use `lpr` on OS X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lp` allows you to specify margins and text size. According to the `man lp`:

```
-o cpi=N
     Sets the number of characters per inch to use when printing a text file. The default is 10.

-o lpi=N
     Sets the number of lines per inch to use when printing a text file. The default is 6.

-o page-bottom=N

-o page-left=N

-o page-right=N

-o page-top=N
     Sets the page margins when printing text files. The values are in points - there are 72 points to the inch.

EXAMPLES

Print a double-sided legal document to a printer called "foo":
    lp -d foo -o media=legal -o sides=two-sided-long-edge filename

Print an image across 4 pages:
    lp -d bar -o scaling=200 filename

Print a text file with 12 characters per inch, 8 lines per inch, and a 1 inch left margin:
    lp -d bar -o cpi=12 -o lpi=8 -o page-left=72 filename
```

Answer (score 4):

I defined a command `mylpr` (in ~/bin) as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
ENSCRIPT="--no-header --margins=36:36:36:36 --font=Courier11 --word-wrap --media=Letter"
export ENSCRIPT
/usr/bin/enscript -p - $1 | /usr/bin/lpr
```

then I also added lines

```
(require 'lpr)
(setq my-print-command "~/bin/mylpr")
(setq lpr-command my-print-command)
```

to my `~/.emacs` and `~/.xemacs/custom.el` files. This took care of all my instances of printing in 12-pt Monaco without margins.

Comment: oops...
I hope what I posted above is clear enough...
I can't edit or comment, so I thank any other user who will do it. Notice that there should be a ";", or a new line, after "export ENSCRIPT".

Comment: Fixed up for you :)