# Changing the font when printing with lpr

Tags: macos, command-line, fonts, lpr

I have searched through the internet, and Super User, but couldn't find the answer. Is it possible to change the font used when printing with `lpr` from Monaco to some other font, like Times New Roman? Currently, I know of no other answer that provides a solution.

My current system is Mac OS X.

Answer (score 5):

`lpr` doesn't allow you to change the font easily (I believe you *can* go change the contents of `/usr/share/cups/fonts`, at least on Linux, but I'm not at a Mac right now...).

An easier way is to convert to Postscript, then print via lpr, as in this shell script [[1]](https://superuser.com/questions/229480/how-do-you-get-lpr-on-os-x-to-print-with-margins-and-a-smaller-font):

```
#!/bin/bash
ENSCRIPT="--no-header --margins=36:36:36:36 --font=Courier11 --word-wrap --media=Letter"
export ENSCRIPT
/usr/bin/enscript -p - $1 | /usr/bin/lpr
```

In this case, for example, save the above as `/usr/local/bin/lprfont`, `chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/lprfont`, and then run as `lprfont somefile.txt`.